# How to output the .pom file for a project

Tags: maven

I have the following in my root project directory:

```
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── mystuff-maven-plugin.iml
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
```

Which when I run `mvn clean install` it generates the following into the target directory (among other things):

```
├── mystuff-maven-plugin-0.0.2-javadoc.jar
├── mystuff-maven-plugin-0.0.2-sources.jar
├── mystuff-maven-plugin-0.0.2.jar
├── classes
```

According to the Sonatype [documentation](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/manual-staging-bundle-creation-and-deployment.html), I need to include the generated .pom file in my final JAR file. Like so:

```
ossrh-test-1.2.pom
ossrh-test-1.2.jar
ossrh-test-1.2-javadoc.jar
ossrh-test-1.2-sources.jar
```

So my question is, where and/or how do I generate a file similar to `ossrh-test-1.2.pom`?

I have located a `.pom` file within the `~/.m2/repository/mystuff-maven-plugin/` directory. That may work but not sure why the `target/` directory doesn't include it.

Comment: If you do a `mvn deploy` the pom.xml you have will be deployed along with the other artifacts under the appropriate name like `mystuff-maven-plugin-0.0.2.pom`? (Is this really a plugin you are creating ?

Comment: I want to sign and deploy manually. That command also does not generate the required `.pom` file. No, I am creating a plugin but have renamed it for the purposes of this question.

Comment: What do you mean by `manually` sign and deploy ?